cd into a directory returns non zero status code
#!/bin/bash -l

source ~/.bashrc

set -e

echo "1. Current dir"
pwd
echo "2. Listing in path ..."
ls
echo "3. Entering dir"
cd bundler
echo "4. Entered"

go@ci-ubuntu-agent-1:/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/x/src$ bash run.sh
1. Current dir
/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/x/src
2. Listing in path ...
bundler  run.sh 
3. Entering dir...
go@ci-ubuntu-agent-1:/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/x/src$ echo $?
1

Why does the cd into the directory return a status code of 1? The directory clearly exists. Only if run via the script the status code is 1. If I directly enter via the command line, status code is 0.
If I remove the -e option and run, the script runs with no issues. What am I missing here?

Can you enter bundler manually? You might be missing permissions to do so. (ls -l could tell you which permissions are set on bundler.) Scripts shouldn't use bash -l, that's for login shells. Plus, you already set #!/bin/bash, why are you starting the script with bash run.sh instead of ./run.sh? Why are you sourcing source ~/.bashrc? Bash already does that for you. Looks like a lot of "read it somewhere" or "trial & error"...

See How can I debug a Bash script?.

Also see BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?).

Here are a couple of options: (1) the directory does not exist, but is a file or something else (2) the directory is not accessible for you (3) the directory you are in was deleted and rewritten by an external process (4) the universe has something special in mind

The directlry exists and am able to enter it manually. I have tried with and without login shell. Both give teh same error. The source is because go cd agents do not source the bashrc and it has to be manually done in the scripts run via the pipelines.

Just tried without sourcing the bashrc and it works. But still confused on why sourcing bashrc should affect anything. When im manually entering the direcoty, the same bashrc is already sourced. Why should it make any difference if its sourced again ?

It's not clear the directory exists, based only on this question. ls only confirms that bundler is a file system entry, which could be a regular file, a named pipe, a character device, a block device, or something else.  Without -e, cd probably still fails, but that's not enough to make the script exit.

It is a directory and I can manually cd into it. Have mentioned it in the question and also in the comments.

@chepner Shouldn't cd produce an error message if the directory doesn't exist?

It's a bit of a red herring to focus on cd's exit status specifically.  The script's cd command exits with non-zero status because it fails, of course, and the thing you seem actually to want to know about is why it fails.

"If I remove the -e option and run, the script runs with no issues".  Yes and no.  Without set -e, the script does not terminate in the event that its cd command fails.  It may therefore print the "4. Entered" message even though the directory was not, in fact, successfully entered.  Try replacing that with something like echo "4. current directory: $(pwd)".

Best guess is that ~/.bashrc is defining a cd function that returns an incorrect status.  Use standard Bash debugging techniques, as described in How can I debug a Bash script? and the Debugging section of BashGuide/Practices - Greg's Wiki, to see exactly what is going on.  A good start would be to run PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:$FUNCNAME: ' bash -x run.sh

This problem illustrates why it is not a good idea to run shell initialization files (like ~/.bashrc) in shell programs.  It is common for initialization files to define wrapper functions for common utilities (including cd) for convenience in interactive shells.  Such functions can cause mysterious, and difficult to debug, problems if they are used in programs.  (It is also common for initialization files to make changes to standard environment variables, such as PATH and CDPATH, that can cause shell programs to malfunction.)

Found the culprit.
Using PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:$FUNCNAME: ' bash -x run.sh as suggested by @pjh, I got the output
+++/home/go/.nvm/bash_completion:99:: complete -o default -F __nvm nvm
+run.sh:5:: set -e
+run.sh:7:: echo '1. Current dir'
1. Current dir
+run.sh:8:: pwd
/home/go
+run.sh:9:: echo '2. Listing in path ...'
2. Listing in path ...
+run.sh:10:: ls
bundler  package-lock.json  r-libs  run.sh
+run.sh:11:: echo '3. Entering dir'
3. Entering dir
+run.sh:12:: cd bundler
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:48:cd: __gvm_is_function __gvm_oldcd
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/_shell_compat:17:__gvm_is_function: local func_name=__gvm_oldcd
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/_shell_compat:19:__gvm_is_function: [[ x__gvm_oldcd == \x ]]
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/_shell_compat:22:__gvm_is_function: builtin declare -f __gvm_oldcd
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/_shell_compat:24:__gvm_is_function: return 0
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:49:cd: __gvm_oldcd bundler
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:22:__gvm_oldcd: builtin cd bundler
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:22:__gvm_oldcd: return 0
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:52:cd: local dot_go_version dot_go_pkgset rslt
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:53:cd: local defaults_go_name defaults_go_pkgset
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:54:cd: local defaults_resolved=false
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:55:cd: local defaults_hash
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:55:cd: defaults_hash=()
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:57:cd: [[ /home/go/.gvm == '' ]]
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:63:cd: [[ '' -eq 1 ]]
+/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:64:cd: defaults_hash=($(__gvm_read_environment_file "${GVM_ROOT}/environments/default"))
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/env/cd:64:cd: __gvm_read_environment_file /home/go/.gvm/environments/default
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:27:__gvm_read_environment_file: [[ -n '' ]]
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:32:__gvm_read_environment_file: local filepath=/home/go/.gvm/environments/default
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:33:__gvm_read_environment_file: local 'regex=^export ([^[:digit:]]+[[:alnum:]_]+);[[:space:]]*([^[:digit:]]+[[:alnum:]_]+=(.*))$'
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:34:__gvm_read_environment_file: local hash
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:34:__gvm_read_environment_file: hash=()
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:36:__gvm_read_environment_file: [[ -z /home/go/.gvm/environments/default ]]
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:36:__gvm_read_environment_file: [[ ! -r /home/go/.gvm/environments/default ]]
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:37:__gvm_read_environment_file: echo ''
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:38:__gvm_read_environment_file: [[ -n '' ]]
++/home/go/.gvm/scripts/function/read_environment_file:42:__gvm_read_environment_file: return 1

I saw that for some reason gvm was returning the 1. This is because I have no gvm envir file. But I didnt see why these particular lines of code should even be invoked.
Following @pjh suggestion that there could be some wrapper on the cd command, I did a comparison of what cd is running between an old machine where this was not a issue and this box.
Old machine cd:
(honeymaker_venv) [go@ci-prod1 ~]$ type cd
cd is a function
cd ()
{
    __zsh_like_cd cd "$@"
}

New machine cd:
root@ci-ubuntu-agent-1:~# su - go
go@ci-ubuntu-agent-1:~$ type cd
cd is a function
cd ()
{
    if __gvm_is_function __gvm_oldcd; then
        __gvm_oldcd $*;
    fi;
    local dot_go_version dot_go_pkgset rslt;
    local defaults_go_name defaults_go_pkgset;
    local defaults_resolved=false;
...... too big to add here

Note: which cd works differently for redhat(old) machines vs debian(new). It returned empty for the new ubuntu machine. so had to use the type
command
The gvm was replacing cd with its own implementation.
A little debugging into gvm's cd wrapper led me to this - https://github.com/moovweb/gvm/issues/457
So I just had to comment out the line in the gvm default load script to not replace cd.
comment out the below line in $GVM_ROOT/scripts/gvm-default
#. "$GVM_ROOT/scripts/env/cd" && cd .

The default cd command works all fine now.
Thanks for the suggestions and debugging help.
